# Using AWS CDK and RDS (Aurora), where can I change the Certificate authority?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cdk, aws-certificate-manager

I am setting up a database cluster (Aurora MySQL 5.7) using [the DatabaseCluster Construct](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-rds.DatabaseCluster.html) from `@aws-cdk/aws-rds`.

My question, where in the setup can I change the *Certificate authority*? I want to programmatically setup the database to use `rds-ca-2019` instead of `rds-ca-2015`. Note, I want to change this using CDK, not by "clicking in the AWS GUI".

The image below shows which setting I am referring to.

[image: Image showing the setting I am trying to change]

I have been browsing the docs for RDS CDK, and tried to Google this without success.

- [This guide describes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL-certificate-rotation.html) the manual steps on how to do this.
- [AWS CDK RDS module](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-rds-readme.html)
- [DatabaseCluster Construct](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-rds.DatabaseCluster.html)
- [Low-level Cluster (CfnCluster)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-rds.CfnDBCluster.html)

BTW, my current current config looks a bit like this:

```
const cluster = new rds.DatabaseCluster(this, 'aurora-cluster', {
    clusterIdentifier: 'aurora-cluster',
    engine: rds.DatabaseClusterEngine.AURORA_MYSQL,
    masterUser: {
        username: 'someuser',
        password: 'somepassword'
    },
    defaultDatabaseName: 'db',
    instances: 2,
    instanceIdentifierBase: 'aurora-',
    instanceProps: {
        instanceType: ...,
        vpcSubnets: {
            subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC,
        },
        vpc: myVpc
    },
    removalPolicy: cdk.RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
    parameterGroup: {
        parameterGroupName: 'default.aurora-mysql5.7'
    },
    port: 3306,
    storageEncrypted: true
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently Cloudformation doesn't support the certificate authority field, and therefore CDK can't either.

https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/211

I upvoted the issue; feel free to join me!

Answer (score 2):

Just came across this while preparing for an [upcoming CA rotation in 2024](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/rotate-your-ssl-tls-certificates-now-amazon-rds-and-amazon-aurora-expire-in-2024/), and it looks like the current accepted answer is outdated.

As per the [current docs at CDK v2.122](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_rds-readme.html#ca-certificate), you should now be able to explicitly specify an RDS Certificate Authority something like:

```js
const cluster = new rds.DatabaseCluster(this, 'Database', {
  engine: rds.DatabaseClusterEngine.auroraMysql({
    version: rds.AuroraMysqlEngineVersion.VER_3_01_0,
  }),
  writer: rds.ClusterInstance.provisioned('writer', {
    // Use 100year-validity RSA4096 cert instead of default: 
    caCertificate: rds.CaCertificate.RDS_CA_RDS4096_G1,
  }),
  readers: [
    rds.ClusterInstance.serverlessV2('reader', {
      // Use 100year-validity RSA4096 cert instead of default: 
      caCertificate: rds.CaCertificate.RDS_CA_RDS4096_G1,
    }),
  ],
  vpc,
});
```